# Why does double-dash work with more command options with npm?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I just came across this command:

```
npm run script ./src/automation/automation_main.ts -- -i payroll_integration
```

I googled about the double dash and it appears to signify the end of command options, per this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/47958

What I don't understand is why there are command options after the double dash (the -i). Can we still include command options even after the double dash?

I ran the above script with and without the double dash, and both appear to run.

Comment: It's not about Bash, but the command you run. It's the one that interprets the arguments it gets, including the double-dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation in your example command is there are two programs being invoked, and both of them use command-line arguments.  You are invoking `npm`, and `npm` will obey the `run script` arguments to invoke the script `automation_main.ts`.  None of the arguments are enclosed in quotes (perhaps that's necessary for this kind of npm command).

The argument `-i payroll_integration` is clearly intended for the script and not for npm.  How do you convince npm to not try to parse it (which will probably make it error out)?

The answer: you insert an argument that tells npm that the rest of words on the line are not npm's arguments.  This is `--`, which means "your arguments stop here, don't worry about the rest".  Npm will remove its arguments up to and including the `--`, and invoke the script with the rest of the line present for the script to parse and use.

Note that, while `bash` and `npm` understand the `--` argument (as many, many other GNU utilities do), there are programs that don't understand it and won't behave the way I described here for `npm`.