# WSL2 Ubuntu won't let me grep recursively?

Tags: ubuntu, grep, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't seem to recursively search with grep for some reason in WSL2.

```
me@SOMEHOST:~$ grep -r -e "DATASTORE_BAKs" --exclude=SOMEHOST-2\.viminfo *
grep: SOMEHOST-2.viminfo: invalid context length argument
```

It seems to have something to do with my `.viminfo` file, but I can't exclude it properly and I can't even ignore the [file using the ignore binary arg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221929/18149).

The file seems to contain alot of `--` characters and I'm wondering if that's screwing it up.

I also did a `file` command on it and it doesn't warrant much:

```
le ./.viminfo
./.viminfo: data
```

How can I make this work again?

Comment: Do you get a different result if you do `grep -r -e "DATASTORE_BAKs" --exclude=SOMEHOST-2\.viminfo -- *` ? It's more likely that you have a file named something like `-ASOMEHOST-2\.viminfo` or `-CSOMEHOST-2\.viminfo` in the current directory

Comment: @steeldriver I already tried looking for a file named that

Comment: Or use `.` instead of `*`?

Comment: There are two possible issues: 1) The backslash is not taken as a directory path delimiter; use just `.viminfo` (the exclusion pattern is only ever tested against the filenames themselves, not against the full pathname). 2) The error is likely due to a file with a name starting with a dash.  This name is likely in the current directory and will be substituted on the command line by the expansion of the `*` glob. Use `-- *` as steeldriver suggests.  This has nothing to do with the `.viminfo` file. This is not an answer, as I don't know what your filenames are in the current directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda ah good catch - I hadn't even considered they were trying to use backslash as a separator (I assumed it was a mistaken belief that the period needed to be escaped)

Comment: @steeldriver `-- *` worked.   What does that do again?

Comment: @leeand00 it tells grep to treat everything following as a non-option (i.e. filename) argument, even if it begins with a `-`. See for example [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Comment: ... although [as @muru pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729788/wsl2-ubuntu-wont-let-me-grep-recursively?noredirect=1#comment1383943_729788) you might want to use `.` instead of `*` (unless your intent is to skip hidden files/directories in the current directory?)

Answer (score -2):

Using `.` insted of `*` works for me.

Comment: Can you say why and _how_ this fixes the issue that the user in the question has?