# Creating an option for 'exec > >(tee -ia $OUT)' to skip stdout

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, exec

I'm trying to **modify** a script that uses the following:

```bash
# first portion of script
# ...
exec > >(tee -ia $OUT)
# ...
# second portion of script
```

The problem I have with this script is that it produces voluminous output to `stdout` (my terminal). The script author included no options for eliminating the terminal output. I would like to add an ***option*** that removes the `stdout`, and get the output solely in the file `$OUT`.

Here's what I've tried:

```bash
TERM_OPT="OFF"

# first portion of script
# ...

if [ $TERM_OPT != "OFF" ]; then
     exec > >(tee -ia $OUT)
else {

# ...
# second portion of script 

} > $OUT
fi
```

This seems to work, but I'm unsure about the use of *curly braces* `{}` in this context as the [GNU secion of Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) (*seems to*) state that a semicolon `;` is required following the list. But adding a `;` or leaving it off seems to make no difference. I've wondered if I should use parentheses `()` instead of curly braces, but this causes everything inside the `()` to execute in a subshell. I'm not particularly keen on that as it's someone else's script & the *subshell* implications are unclear to me (I didn't try this).

The other thing I tried *seemed like* a hack, but I read of others using it, and it seems to work OK also:

```bash
TERM_OPT="OFF"

# first portion of script
# ...

if [ $TERM_OPT != "OFF" ]; then
     exec > >(tee -ia $OUT)
else
     exec > >(tee -ia $OUT 1> /dev/null)
fi

# ...
# second portion of script
```

I like this as it seems more *self-contained*, but that's not much of a consideration AFAICT.

**So the Question is:**  What's the correct way to do this? By that, I mean what's the correct way to **opt out** of the terminal output after an `exec > >(tee -ia $OUT)`? Is one of these solutions preferable to the other - or do I need to do something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Only* redirecting to the `$OUT` file in `a`ppend mode is much easier:

```
case $TERM_OPT in
  (OFF) exec >> "$OUT";;
  (*)   exec > >(tee -ia -- "$OUT")
esac
```

Beware the shell doesn't wait for `tee` upon exiting, so you might find that `tee` is still outputting something after your script has finished.

```
$ bash -c 'exec > >(tee -ia -- file); echo A'; echo B; sleep 1
B
A
```

See how `A` was output after B.

To work around that, you can add:

```
if [ "$TERM_OPT" != OFF ]; then
  exec > /dev/null # closes the pipe to tee which should cause tee
                   # to see EOF on input and exit
  wait # waits for all asynchronous tasks including tee
fi
```

At the end of the script or in an `EXIT` trap.

Another option (which would also work in sh) is to put your whole script inside a `main` function and do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
main() {
  # your script here
}
case $TERM_OPT in
  (OFF) main "$@" >> "$OUT";;
  (*)   main "$@" | tee -ia -- "$OUT"
esac
```

Comment: What's the significance of the *double dash* `--`?

Comment: See [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210) (especially the ⚠️ part)

Comment: Still a bit fuzzy on this (though your explanation was quite good)... does the `--` mark the last **option**, and therefore anything following must be an argument?

Comment: Yes, it marks the end of options, you use it to make sure nothing past it will be treated as an option even if it starts with - or +. Here, `$OUT` is variable so may very well start with `-` like in `OUT=---myfile---.log`

Comment: One more Q: *"Beware the shell doesn't wait for tee upon exiting, ..."* I would think you would **want** the shell to wait on `tee`?? By that I mean, if `tee` has not finished writing the output file (due to a slow HDD maybe) shouldn't the shell keep the process open until it finishes?

Comment: Thing is here, `tee` doesn't finish until it sees the end of its input. If the shell, whose stdout is redirected to the pipe to tee doesn't terminate then tee doesn't terminate so the shell would never stop if it was waiting for tee. You need to actively close that pipe like we do here with `exec > /dev/null` for `tee` to terminate (assuming there's no other background process with stdout or other fd redirected  to that pipe).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect stdout to be appended to a file, and not also have a copy of the output on the terminal, just do:

```
exec >> "$OUT"
```

The only purpose of `tee` is to duplicate one stream into multiple, so if you only want the output in one place, there's no need for it. Your `tee -ia "$OUT" > /dev/null` would of course also work, but that's a bit silly: you'd still be duplicating the output, just to discard the other copy.

> I'm unsure about the use of curly braces `{}` in this context

Braces require a semicolon, or a newline. It actually says that in the manual: *"The semicolon (or newline) following list is required."* Parenthesis require neither.

The implications of a subshell are that the subshell runs in an independent copy of the shell, and any changes in the subshell are not visible outside it. If the script ends anyway when the subshell ends, that doesn't mean much, and all the subshell does is start an unneeded process.

I would go with something like

```
if [ "$TERM_OPT" != "OFF" ]; then
     exec > >(tee -ia -- "$OUT")
else
     exec >> "$OUT"
fi
```